# Screen redirection takes time to execute after asynchronous call in React-native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-router-flux

I am developing a small app with Expo, React-native-router-flux, firebase and react-redux. I am trying to implement a launch screen that appears after the splash screen and checks if the user is loaded or not.  The launch screen calls the following action inside componentDIdMount function:

```
export const tryToSignInSilently = user => {
  return () => {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(Actions);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (user != null) Actions.tabbar();
      else Actions.LoginScreen();
    }, 1000);
  };
};
```

I had to add that setTimeout to be able to redirect the screen otherwise, it would not change screen.  1) Is that the recommended solution to the problem?

After It redirects to the login screen and the submit button is pressed, another action is created:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
return dispatch => {   

dispatch({ type: LOGIN });
console.log("This executes");

FirebaseService.signIn(email, password)
  .then(user => {
    console.log("This takes almost a minute to execute");
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
    Actions.tabbar();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL });
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(
        i18n.t("app.attention"),
        i18n.t("login.enter.message"),
        [{ text: i18n.t("app.ok") }],
        { cancelable: true }
      );
    }
  }); };};
```

FirebaseService.signIn  function =>

```
static async signIn(email, password) {
return await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  }
```

The interesting note is: If I press the submit button in the login screen, and save the code (causing the live reload), the firebase function is executed immediately and the page is correctly redirected to the home screen.
2) What could be causing that behavior?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate your  component with a  using useContext hook approach. 
Do all the login inside the context component by using useEffect hook with the Firebase function onAuthStateChanged. See sample code below:

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [userObject, setUserObject] = useState(null); 
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);


useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user){
        setLoggedIn(true);
        setUserObject(user);
      }
      else {
          setLoggedIn(false);
          setUserObject(null);
      }
  });
// Cleanup subscription on unmount
return () => unsubscribe();

  }, []);

 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

return(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, userObject }}>{ children }</AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

}

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };

Then on the launch screen use the context variable 'loggedIn'  to detect if the user is already loggedin or not.